# Multi-channel "local variation augmentation"

Tags: numpy, scipy, data-augmentation

I'm trying to augment my sensor data (M samples x N channels) according to a method called "local variation augmentation" described in *[EMGSense: A Low-Effort Self-Supervised Domain Adaptation Framework for EMG Sensing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10099164)*. If you can't view the paper, here's the description:

[image: the description]

My best attempt so far is the code below, but the augmentation seems more sever than what the paper shows. Also, I'm augmenting each channel in a for loop, and there must be a more efficient way to augment all channels at once. Lastly, with `interp1d` I cannot fill in values outside the sampled indicies `I`, so I cannot apply the "warping function" to all `L_X` points.. Any help is appreciated!

```
class LocalVariationAug(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Simulate local changes of speed and intensity in a signal"""

    def __init__(self, seed=42) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)

    def fit(self, X):
        return self

    def transform(self, X: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:
        """_summary_

        :param X: _description_
        :type X: np.ndarray
        :return: augmented signals
        :rtype: _type_

        Steps:
        1. randomly select Lx/3 indices
        2. randomly select Lx/3 points from a normal distribution N(1, 0.1)
        3. Using the two above, fit a wrapping curve g and calculate the corresponding values
        4. Element-wise multiply G and X to obtain X_a
        5. calc cumsum of G, G~
        6. Element-wise multiply G~ and range(1, len(X) + 1, 1), and sort to obtain I'
        7. Using I' and X_a to fit a new time-warping curve function h
        8. Use h to calculate the augmented signal
        """
        if X.ndim != 2:
            raise RuntimeError("Only 2d arrays are supported")

        L_X = X.shape[0]
        I = np.sort(self.rng.choice(range(L_X), L_X // 3, replace=False))
        S = self.rng.normal(1, 0.1, L_X // 3)
        g = interp1d(I, S, kind="quadratic")
        x = np.arange(L_X)
        G = np.ones_like(x, dtype=np.float32)  # G as a vector to be element-wise multiplied by all channels - it contains values uniformly distributed around 1 to modify channels intensities.
        I_min, I_max = I.min(), I.max()
        G[I_min:I_max] = g(x[I_min:I_max])
        X_a = X * G[..., None]

        G_telda = np.cumsum(G)
        I_prime = G_telda * (x + 1) / L_X

        Ip_min, Ip_max = I_prime.min(), I_prime.max()
        X_a2 = None
        for col in range(X_a.shape[1]):
            h = interp1d(I_prime, X_a[:, col], kind="quadratic")
            x_a = h(x[math.ceil(Ip_min) : int(Ip_max)])
            if X_a2 is None:
                X_a2 = np.empty((x_a.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
            X_a2[:, col] = x_a
        return X_a2


X = (np.sin(x) + np.cos(x * 1.4) + np.cos(x * 0.7) + np.cos(x * 1.4) * np.sin(x))
X = np.column_stack((X, X))  # two channels
t = LocalVariationAug()
X_a = t.transform(X)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(X[:, 1], label="X")
plt.plot(X_a[:, 1], label="X_a")
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image: Output]